# convert text box value into array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have passed the json value in textbox and I want to get the textbox value and get the value in [

```js
const data={"geo_details":["US East","Us West","Europe","UK"]};
myJSON=JSON.stringify(data);
obj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
var username=(obj.geo_details);
var testval;
$("input[name='username_hidden']").val(username);
var test=$(".username_hidden").val();
$.each(test, function (key, entry) {
             testval.push(entry);
            });
console.log(testval);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name='username_hidden' class='username_hidden' value=''>
```

]

I tried to get the value and make the format as

```
["US East","Us West","Europe","UK"]
```

Comment: Why do you stringify and then parse the json? The format you wanted already in data.geo_details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use .split() to split the array `,` and console.log the empty array with value in it.

Also, you do not see to do this `JSON.stringify` and use `JSON.parse`.

You data is already an object you can access it straight.

Run snippet to see it in action.

```js
const data = {
  "geo_details": ["US East", "Us West", "Europe", "UK"]
};

//Assign Val
const username = (data.geo_details);
$("input[name='username_hidden']").val(username);

//Empty Array
var testval = [];

//Get Input Val
const text = $(".username_hidden").val();
const arr = text.split(',');

$.each(arr, function(key, entry) {
  testval.push(entry);
});

console.log(testval);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name='username_hidden' class='username_hidden' value=''>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you trying to get an array of the comma separated text input. This will do what you wanted.

```js
$('#submit').click(function(){

  let text = $('.myinput').val();
  let arr = text.split(',');
  console.log(arr);
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" name='username_hidden' value="US East,Us West,Europe,UK" class='myinput' value=''>
<button id="submit">Go</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```
var test=$(".username_hidden").val();
var res = test.split(',')
```